# Input radio en v-for VUE

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Estoy intentando crear un pequeño sistema de preguntas basadas solo en dos respuestas "SI" y "NO", para ello estoy usando `VUE` todo iba bien hasta que me topé con los radio `inputs`, ya que creé dos radio `inputs` para las respuestas, pero me genera problemas de duplicados y al realizar clic en el radio no hace el clic correcto.

Demo:

```js
var questions = new Vue({
    el: '#main',
    data: {
     chosenindex:0,
      questions :[
        {
          "id": 1,
          "question": "PRIMERA PARTE",
          "chosenanswer": null,
          "options": [
            {
              "id": 1,
              "answer": "Tiene sed?",
            },
            {
              "id": 2,
              "answer": "Tiene sueño?",
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "question": "SEGUNDA PARTE",
          "chosenanswer": 0,
          "options": [
            {
              "id": 3,
              "answer": "Tiene hambre?",
            },
            {
              "id": 4,
              "answer": "Tiene cansancio?",
            }
          ]
        },
      ],
    },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="main">
<template v-for="(question,qindex) in questions">
  <template v-if="chosenindex == qindex">
    <p>
    {{question.question}}
    </p>
    <template v-for="(option,oindex) in question.options" >
      {{option.answer}} <br>
       <input type="radio" :value="0" :name="question.id"
                v-model="question.chosenanswer" :key="option.id" /> NO
       <input type="radio" :value="1" :name="question.id"
                v-model="question.chosenanswer" :key="option.id" /> SI                             
       <br/>
    </template>
  </template>
</template>
<button type="button" v-if="chosenindex!=0" v-on:click="chosenindex--">Previous</button>
<button type="button" v-if="chosenindex<1" v-on:click="chosenindex++">Next</button>
</div>
```

Al final deseo sumar las respuestas de los questions por grupos, es decir :

```
PRIMERA PARTE = 2
SEGUNDA PARTE = 1
```

> La suma se realiza con las respuestas SI = 1 NO = 0

FUNCIONANDO: https://jsfiddle.net/killerbo/09xukz4a/

Comment: No termino de entender cual es tu problema...

Comment: Hola gbianchi, el problema es con los radio inputs creados, no funcionan correctamente. saludos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que sólo tienes un campo `chosenanswer` para el objeto `question`, pero haces el *binding* de las dos opciones al mismo campo. Por eso "se duplica el click".

Cada objeto `answer` debería tener su propio `chosenanswer` con su *binding* a su respectivo `<option>`.

```
    {
      "id": 1,
      "question": "PRIMERA PARTE",
      "options": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "answer": "Tiene sed?",
          "chosenanswer": null // Aquí el campo para esta answer
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "answer": "Tiene sueño?",
          "chosenanswer": null // Y aqui de nuevo
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      // ...
    }
];
```

En el HTML no haría falta nada más que hacer el *binding* al campo del `option`, no de `question`.

```
<template v-for="(option,oindex) in question.options" >
    {{option.answer}} <br>
    <input type="radio" :value="0" :name="question.id"
            v-model="option.chosenanswer" :key="option.id" /> NO
    <input type="radio" :value="1" :name="question.id"
            v-model="option.chosenanswer" :key="option.id" /> SI                             
    <br/>
</template>
```

---

**EDIT:** Sumar las respuestas.

En el caso del "Sí" es sencillo, sólo necesitamos sumar todos los `chosenanswer`, ya que el valor puede ser `null`, `0` ó `1`. En el caso de `null`, también contará como un `0`.
En el caso del "No" es un poco más complicado, porque tenemos que discernir los `null` de los `0`, para evitar falso-positivo. Por ello, saco un poco de provecho de los *type coercion* de *JavaScript*.

```
methods: {
    check: function(e) {
      // De la primera pregunta
    const [ first ] = this.questions;
    const nSi = first.options.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr.chosenanswer, 0);
    const nNo = first.options.reduce((acc, curr) => {
        // Compruebo que sea 0 (y solo 0)
        const is0 = curr.chosenanswer === 0;
        // Convierto el bool a number
        // true -> 1; false -> 0
        return acc + +is0;
    }, 0);

    console.log(`SI: ${nSi}`);
    console.log(`NO: ${nNo}`);
  }
}
```

Algo que se me había olvidado comentar antes. Los *radio button* deberían tener *key* diferente. En caso de sacar la *key* de cada `option`, siempre se duplican. Por ello deberías quitar el atributo *key*.
Además, el atributo *name* debería estar ligado al `option`, no al `question`.

Así quedaría de nuevo el HTML

```
<template v-for="(option,oindex) in question.options" >
{{option.answer}} <br>
    <input type="radio" :value="0" :name="option.id"
            v-model="option.chosenanswer" /> NO
    <input type="radio" :value="1" :name="option.id"
            v-model="option.chosenanswer" /> SI                  
    <br/>
</template>
```

Espero que sirva.

Comment: Gracias, funciona, como puedo sumar esas respuestas cuando le doy clic en siguiente?